# Selenium Python best way to optimize RAM consumption

Tags: selenium, selenium-chromedriver, webautomation

I'm coding a scripts that needs Selenium. As you know it requires lots of RAM power. So I tried with different browsers for the same script. Firefox required 120MB, Opera about 60MB. The best result I got was with chrome (35MB), with the following settings:

```
options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument('--allow-insecure-localhost') # differ on driver version. can ignore.
prefs = {'profile.default_content_setting_values': {'cookies': 2, 'images': 2, 'javascript': 2, 
                            'plugins': 2, 'popups': 2, 'geolocation': 2, 
                            'notifications': 2, 'auto_select_certificate': 2, 'fullscreen': 2, 
                            'mouselock': 2, 'mixed_script': 2, 'media_stream': 2, 
                            'media_stream_mic': 2, 'media_stream_camera': 2, 'protocol_handlers': 2, 
                            'ppapi_broker': 2, 'automatic_downloads': 2, 'midi_sysex': 2, 
                            'push_messaging': 2, 'ssl_cert_decisions': 2, 'metro_switch_to_desktop': 2, 
                            'protected_media_identifier': 2, 'app_banner': 2, 'site_engagement': 2, 
                            'durable_storage': 2}}
options.add_experimental_option('prefs', prefs)
options.add_argument("disable-infobars")
options.add_argument("--disable-extensions")
options.add_argument("--disable-javascript")
caps = options.to_capabilities()
caps["acceptInsecureCerts"] = True
driver = webdriver.Chrome(desired_capabilities=caps)
```

I would like to know if there are settings or advices in order to consume less than 35MB. Thank you.